# How can I change the viewing settings on OzMF?

Tags: metafont

I've been learning how to use MetaFont, and I found the program OzMF, which I like. However, when I type

```
mode_setup
beginchar(65,10pt#,10pt#,0pt#)
    pickup pencircle scaled 0.2pt;
    z1=(0, 0.5h); z2=(w, 0.5h);
    draw z1..z2..cycle;
    endchar;
end
```

I get something that looks like this:

[image]

I would like to change the viewing screen so that the character is fully visible, maybe even centered. Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: is this the metafont that comes with the (shareware) oztex distribution?  (i know of no-one ... apart, possibly, from you ... who still uses oztex.)

Comment: I don't use OzTeX; I normally use the MacTeX distribution. But yes, OzMF comes with standard OzTeX.